# How can I attached title, content and date on the template

Tags: html, django

As for now I am following a video to create a blog with django. But, I have problem attaching the title, content, author and date on the template which I had downloaded from colorlib. I used the method below in the index.html file but they do now show:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% load static %}

{% block content %}
{% for post in object_list %}
<div class="site-section">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-8">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-12">
            <div class="section-title">
              <h2>Editor's Pick</h2>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="post-entry-1">
              <a href="#"><img src="{% static 'images/img_h_1.jpg' %}" alt="Image" class="img-fluid"></a>
              <h2><a href="{{ obj.title }}"></a></h2>
              <p>{{ obj.overview }}</p>
              <div class="post-meta">
                <span class="d-block">
                <a href="#">{{ obj.author.user.username }}</a> in <a href="#">{{ cat }}</a></span>
                <span class="date-read">{{ obj.timestamp|timesince }} ago<span class="mx-1">&bullet;</span> 3 min read <span class="icon-star2"></span></span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming object_list is the list of posts. You instantiated the loop variable as post. Therefore post is the variable representing a post instead of obj which you try to access. So replace everywhere you have obj with post or you can make the loop variable obj instead. Either way

Comment: Welcome to programming. Wish you best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

Since you are iterating through each **post** from the list of posts, so to access the value of each post, you should use `{{ post.title }}` to show the title of the post, `{{ post.author.username }}` to show the username of the author of the post, and so on.